# PHP Title, Description and Keywords Per Page

Tags: php, regex, seo

I'm trying to figure out a way to create description and keywords per page.

For the title it would be:

```
{{title=some page title in here}}
```

For descriptions, I would do something like this:

```
{{description=some description per page in here}}
```

Also for keywords meta tag, I would do something like this:

```
{{keywords=example keyword, per each page, this is an example}}
```

How would I achive this with preg_replace + regex parsing, also so it would not be visible on the page it self but placed in the actual meta information such as:

```
<title> some page title in here </title>
<meta name="description" content="some description per page in here">
<meta name="keywords" content="example keyword, per each page, this is an example">
```

Example page would look like this:

```
{{title=some page title in here}}
{{description=some description per page in here}}
{{keywords=example keyword, per each page, this is an example}}

<div id="content">
  <h4> Some page title here </h4>
  <p> Some page paragraphs here. </p>
</div> <!--#content-->
```

and of course result would be simular to this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> Website Title - some page title in here </title>
  <meta name="description" content="some description per page in here">
  <meta name="keywords" content="example keyword, per each page, this is an example">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <h4> Some page title here </h4>
    <p> Some page paragraphs here. </p>
  </div> <!--#content-->
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: I feel like jQuery would be a better solution for something like this...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: What would regex be for {{title=some page title in here}} and {{description=some description per page in here}}
 and {{keywords=example keyword, per each page, this is an example}} to do this parsing

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you want to include something like this:

```
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
```

Where page title has been set earlier in the script

Comment: Can you give a reason for this? Are you allowed to use preg_replace_callback() ?

Comment: yes any preg is preferd actually =) I'm trying to code my own parser and trying to figure out regex for the above examples.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `regex` to do this. Have the metadata of the page in an array like this:

```
$meta["title"] = "Title";
$meta["description"] = "Description of the Page";
$meta["keywords"] = "Keywords, SEO";
```

Output the three this way:

```
<title><?php echo $meta["title"]; ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta["description"]; ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $meta["keywords"]; ?>">
```

Comment: Again, this wont work, I need actual preg_replace + regex to do something like this {{title=some title here}} So I can use it as I showed in the example above.

Comment: Yeah, so I can use custom elements in my pages. Like = Heading 1 = and __underline text__ etc. The trick is to allow regular HTML/HTML5. But at same time allow parsing of my custom elements in the page.

Comment: I've actually found this > http://pastebin.com/wSarUysb
from some php class, it does simular to what I need to do but I can't seem to extend it to GeSHi sourcecode highlighting for sourcecode tags properly. Also, I want to use my custom elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

To match any given tag:

```
/(?<=\{\{TAG_NAME=).*?(?=\}\})/
```

To match variable tags:

```
/\{\{(\w*?)=(.*?)\}\}/
```

Then, the first submatch will give you the tag name, the second will give you the the value.  To account for whitespace:

```
/\{\{\s*(\w*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}/
```

... so long as noone uses a '}}' within a tag.

A break down:

```
\{\{
```

Match two open braces.  Easy.  (they have to be escaped because the { is a special character in regex.

```
\s*
```

Greedily match as much white space as you can.

```
(\w*?)
```

match the shortest string of word characters(a-zA-Z0-9, and underscore) that won't break the regex.  The parenthesis return the stuff matched here as a sub match.

```
\s*=\s*
```

Gobble up more whitespace with exactly one equals sign

```
(.*?)
```

Match the shortest set of any characters that won't break the regex, and return it as the second sub match.

```
\s*\}\}
```

Gobble up the last of the white space and the closing braces (again, escaped).

So, if you do:

```
$regex = '/\{\{\s*(\w*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*\}\}/'
preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches)
$html = preg_replace($regex, '', $html)
```

Then `$matches[1]` has all your tag names, and `$matches[2]` has all their values, and `$html` has all your remaining html